# How do I locate my file/image in tkinter without C: User?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I make a code that locates the image inside a folder without using the direct location with C:User. So that whenever I send the GUI to someone, they can run it without any errors. Is there any other codes that I can use?

```
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Me/Downloads/xxxx/Pics/xxxx.png")
label = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Comment: There is not enough information to give an answer.  Is the `Pics` directory inside the directory where the script is?  How do you pack your application to *someone*? .. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a bit between the lines, it sounds like:

1. You want to distribute your code by sending a directory or archive to people so that they can run it on their machine
2. You have resources inside this package that you'd like to reference

You can't really assume anything about where the user will place this directory on their machine, so you need to work with relative paths.

This line:

```
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(downloadsDirectory,"xxxx","Pics","xxxx.png"))
```

seems to suggest your script is placed in folder `xxxx` of the user's `Downloads` directory, which means the relative path of the resource is `Pics/xxxx.png`.

Based on these assumptions, you could do something like:

```
from pathlib import Path

script_dir = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
resource_path = script_dir / "Pics" / "xxxx.png"

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=str(resource_path))  # use resource_path.as_posix() instead if you want forward slashes on all platforms instead of native path format
label = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pathlibe instead, if you want to access user home, it will also work in LINUX OR MacOS as its platform independent

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

downloadsDirectory = os.path.join(Path.home(),'Downloads')
photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(downloadsDirectory,"xxxx","Pics","xxxx.png"))
label = tk.Label(window, image=photo)
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```